# IIS URL Rewrite -- Why is my QueryString Appending inconsistent?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use IIS URL Rewrite for a few things, one of which is taking the subdomain provided by the user and appending the subdomain text as a querystring (essentially, I'm using it to separate user files). Something weird is happening though, under certain conditions.

I have a few links that all react differently and return different values when entered.

1. `http://something.domain.com/courses`

   - redirects to `http://something.domain.com/courses/?subdomain=something` **unexpected**
2. `http://something.domain.com/courses/`

   - redirects to `http://something.domain.com/courses/` **as expected** (or so I expect it to)
3. `http://something.domain.com/courses/list`

   - redirects to `http://something.domain.com/courses/list` **as expected** (or so I expect it to)

The main problem with this, is for some reason, when the `?subdomain=something` is sent in the first example, my code doesn't react correctly. It basically removes the parameter. The other problem I have with this, is it just looks ugly, because it only happens in certain use cases, and its in the most common use case (who goes out of their way to put a trailing `/`?)

A similar thing happens when I view my Admin page, however, there are 2 of the 3 cases that return unexpectedly

1. `http://something.domain.com/admin/`

   - returns `http://something.domain.com/admin/?subdomain=something#/` **unexpected**
2. `http://something.domain.com/admin`

   - returns `http://something.domain.com/admin/?subdomain=something#/` **unexpected**
3. `http://something.domain.com/admin/#/`

   - returns `http://something.domain.com/admin/#/` **as expected**

---

Since there is no rule attached to the Admin example, it leads me to believe it has something to do with the Subdomain Rule, but I have no clue what it is.

**Notes**

I have tried using `appendQueryString="true"` and `appendQueryString="false"`.

I use `stopProcessing="false"` on the Subdomain Rule because it should apply to **every** request made.

---

#### Subdomain Rewrite Rule

```
<rule name="RewriteSubdomainToQuery" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)*(\w+)\.(.*)(\.com)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}?subdomain={C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

---

#### Course Rewrite Rule

```
<rule name="RewriteCoursesHandler" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^courses/?([^/]*)$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="courses/index.asp?view={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: could you share what is your exact requirement? you could try to use failed request tracing to get what more detail what is going wrong. what is the order of the rule? seems I tried your rule but I did not get the same result as yours. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis